# Angle of intersection between a plane and sphere.

Tags: differential-geometry

> Let $X(\theta,\phi)=(\sin \theta \cos \phi, \sin\theta\sin \phi, \cos\theta)$ be parametrization of the sphere $S^2$. Let $P$ be the plane $x=z \cot\alpha$, $0<\alpha<\pi$ and $\beta$ be the angle wich the curve $P\cap S^2$ makes with the semimeridian $\phi=\phi_0$. Compute $\cos \beta$.

I know how is the procedure but I get stuck calculating an adequate parametrization of the curve $P\cap S^2$.

Anybody know another approach to calculate $\cos \beta$?

Thanks for help!

Comment: What are $u$ and $v$? Did you mean $\phi$ and $\theta$? Why are you calling this function $x$, when this is the name of one of your Cartesian coordinates? Why did you bother with a parametrization, when the sphere is just the unit sphere centered at the origin?

Comment: I fixed the $u$ and $v$. I don't see any problem with the $x$. I asked for another approach because I am thinking in a parametrization and I get stuck. Can you help?

Comment: Anyway, I changed the $x$.

Comment: Well, your circle is a great circle on the sphere going through $(0,\pm1,0)$, isn’t it? Seems to me you should be able to find the intersection point with your semimeridian easily enough. Make sure you have an accurate picture, in your mind at least.

Comment: I get the equation $\tan \theta=\displaystyle\frac{\cot\alpha}{\cos \phi_0}$. And in the point $(\theta_0, \phi_0)$ those curves intersect where $\theta_0$ is the solution of the equation above... but I don't get how to calculate $\cos \beta$

Comment: Don’t you have a right triangle, spherical triangle, that is? To save yourself trouble, just look up Napier’s rules, which relate all parts of a triangle.